# How to use a while loop result within three dimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, while-loop

I would like to pass a while loop result as a value to three dimensional array,i have tried but i couldn't get it.I am trying to solve this from few days.Any suggestions or answers are appreciated.Thank you

```
    $messages = array(
   'sender' => "akhil",
   'messages' => array(
    //////////////while loop starts
    while($i < $data){   
    array(
        'number' =>$data[$i],//////here i want to pass the while loop 
          variable
        'text' => rawurlencode('Hello,.........')
      ) 
    $i++;
    }
    /////////////while loop ends

     )
    );


  ///the would like to get the below result 


   $messages = array(
 'sender' => "akhil",
  'messages' => array(
    array(
        'number' => 918xxxxxx,
        'text' => rawurlencode('Hello,------')
    ),
    array(
        'number' => 9196xxxxxx,
        'text' => rawurlencode('Hello,----')
    )
    ), array(
        'number' => 919xxxxx,
        'text' => rawurlencode('Hello,----')
    )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create the array outside the while loop and then push values into it inside the loop. Your code is almost there...

```
$messages = array('sender' => "akhil",
                  'messages' => array()
                 );
while ($i < count($data)) {   
    $messages['messages'][] = array('number' => $data[$i],
                                    'text' => rawurlencode('Hello,.........'));
    $i++;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PENSAl)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called an [Anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).
You can achieve your expected behavior by doing this:

```
'messages' => (function(){
  $res = [];
  while($i < $data){
    $res[] = [
      'number' =>$data[$i],//////here i want to pass the while loop variable
      'text' => rawurlencode('Hello,.........')
    ];
    $i++;
  }
  return $res;
})(),
...
```

I do not know the exact structure of your data, but I would swap the `while` for an [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). It would look like this:

```
'messages' => array_map(function($d){
  return [
     'number' =>$d,
     'text' => rawurlencode('Hello,.........')
  ]
},$data),
...
```

Hohpe that helps,

Comment: Thank you , i got idea on how to use array_map() now.

Comment: Awesome! Best of luck :)